# How can I find a table after a text string using BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from several web pages which are not uniform in how they display their tables.  I need to write code that will search for a text string and then go to the table immediately following that specific text string.  Then I want to extract the contents of that table.  Here's what I've got so far:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import re

html = ['<html><body><p align="center"><b><font size="2">Table 1</font></b><table><tr><td>1. row 1, cell 1</td><td>1. row 1, cell 2</td></tr><tr><td>1. row 2, cell 1</td><td>1. row 2, cell 2</td></tr></table><p align="center"><b><font size="2">Table 2</font></b><table><tr><td>2. row 1, cell 1</td><td>2. row 1, cell 2</td></tr><tr><td>2. row 2, cell 1</td><td>2. row 2, cell 2</td></tr></table></html>']
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(html))
searchtext = re.compile('Table 1',re.IGNORECASE) # Also need to figure out how to ignore space
foundtext = soup.findAll('p',text=searchtext)
soupafter = foundtext.findAllNext()
table = soupafter.find('table') # find the next table after the search string is found
rows = table.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    for td in cols:
        try:
            text = ''.join(td.find(text=True))
        except Exception:
            text = ""
        print text+"|",
print
```

However, I get the following error:

```
    soupafter = foundtext.findAllNext()
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'findAllNext'
```

Is there an easy way to do this using BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 10):

The error is due to the fact that [`findAllNext`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#findAllNext%28name,%20attrs,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs%29%20and%20findNext%28name,%20attrs,%20text,%20**kwargs%29) is a method of `Tag` objects, but `foundtext` is a `ResultSet` object, which is a *list* of matching tags or strings.  You could iterate through the each of the tags in `foundtext`, but depending on your needs it might be sufficient to use [`find`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#find%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20**kwargs%29), which returns only the first matching tag.

Here's a modified version of your code.  After changing `foundtext` to use `soup.find`, I found and fixed the same problem with `table`.  I modified your regex to [ignore whitespace between the words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590298/how-to-ignore-whitespace-in-a-regular-expression-subject-string):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import re

html = ['<html><body><p align="center"><b><font size="2">Table 1</font></b><table><tr><td>1. row 1, cell 1</td><td>1. row 1, cell 2</td></tr><tr><td>1. row 2, cell 1</td><td>1. row 2, cell 2</td></tr></table><p align="center"><b><font size="2">Table 2</font></b><table><tr><td>2. row 1, cell 1</td><td>2. row 1, cell 2</td></tr><tr><td>2. row 2, cell 1</td><td>2. row 2, cell 2</td></tr></table></html>']
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(html))
searchtext = re.compile(r'Table\s+1',re.IGNORECASE)
foundtext = soup.find('p',text=searchtext) # Find the first <p> tag with the search text
table = foundtext.findNext('table') # Find the first <table> tag that follows it
rows = table.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    for td in cols:
        try:
            text = ''.join(td.find(text=True))
        except Exception:
            text = ""
        print text+"|",
    print
```

This outputs:

```
1. row 1, cell 1| 1. row 1, cell 2|
1. row 2, cell 1| 1. row 2, cell 2|
```