# How can I ignore additional spaces in a string using regex and c#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to ignore whitespace in a regular expression subject string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590298/how-to-ignore-whitespace-in-a-regular-expression-subject-string)

I am using the following:

```
"<a href=\"(.+?)\">(.+?)</a>"
```

to match:

```
"<a href="x">xx</a>"
```

However sometimes my users are entering the following:

```
"<a   href="x" >xx</a>"
"<a href="x">xx</a>"
"<a href="x"   >xx</a>"
```

How can I modify the regex so that it matches on one or many spaces in the three strings above?

Comment: Please, don't post a link to that dont-parse-html-with-regex answer...

Comment: it is a simple answer if you would think only about regex, but usually to use regex to process html is not a good idea, because in your case user may add line break, add four spaces, add another attribute, etc.

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex?  Why not use something like string.Replace()?

Comment: @BlackBear - Why not?  There's good reasons for it.

Comment: Check this one out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to add `\s*` where a whitespace is legal but not required, and `\s+` in places where whitespace is required, like this:

```
<a\\s+href\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"\\s*>([^<]*)</a>
```

On the other hand, this is precisely an example of why one shouldn't attempt to parse XML or HTML with regex: it is simply a wrong tool for the job. Using one of several XML parsing techniques available in .NET would provide a much better alternative.

Comment: +1 Using a verbatim string would make it much more readable though

Comment: @BlackBear I thought about it, but it would require me to double the quotes, so it's a tradeoff either way (although I agree that there are only three quotes and four `\s`s, so verbatim wins on points).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Can you tell me the names of some XML parsing techniques so I can google them and look into these. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Anne Look up "XmlReader" and `LINQ2XML`. There's also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/56107/335858) if you are interested in parsing HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Negative lookahead assertion `(?!\s)` so it won't match if there is whitespace...

```
<a (?!\s)href=\"(?!\s)(.+?)\"(?!\s)>(?!\s)(.+?)</a>
```

But just from the amount of times this needs to be added, you can see that using a Regex for this is probably not the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol you want is `+`. will match one-or-more spaces.

```
<a +href=\"(.+?)\" *>(.+?)</a>
```

However, parsing html via regular expressions is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little funky and probably not the best, but here it goes:

```
string.Join(" ", s.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

edit: (I know it's not regex)