# Finding matches in Django model without punctuation or spaces

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I'm trying to match a string that is a GET from the URL, to a field in the database that is the same string without any punctuation or spaces. For example:

```
URL: http://www.mysite.com/JohnBSmith/

And the string I'm trying to match in the database is: "John B. Smith"
```

Can I do this with regex? One catch is that I don't know how many punctuation marks or spaces there will be.

How do I do this with Django? I want to write this in the form:

> myVariable = MyModel.objects.filter(foo=bar)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but my point was that I'm looking for something of the the form MyModel.objects.filter(something....)

Comment: Other formats would be fine, but that would be preferable

Comment: Is `"John B. Smith"` stored as a single database entry ?

Comment: I would like the URL to not have any dashes or symbols

Comment: @karthikr, yes, "John B. Smith" is one field in the database.

Comment: Regex in queries can get inefficient very quickly.

Comment: [One crude way to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4590313/1628832)

Comment: The second part of your question makes no sense @jball037.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend adding a new column to your table, a new field to your model, maybe a [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) and to ensure that when you save your model instance that this field is updated. You could use for this purpose [django-autoslug](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-autoslug).

Answer (score 1):

This could be the regex:

`John +B(\.)? +Smith`