# Ignore spaces between a groups of numbers in regex?

Tags: regex

Hello I am attempting to read vat  numbers in regex with the country code in front:

`GB 009 0009 09`

that they could be formatted as so

```
GB009000909
GB 009000909
GB 0 09 0009 09
```

My current expression is: `(GB\d{9}\b|GB\s{1}\d{9}\b)`

How do i go about keeping it simple and ignoring spaces?

Comment: may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590298/how-to-ignore-whitespace-in-a-regular-expression-subject-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GB(\s?\d){9}`

`GB` matches the characters GB literally (case sensitive)

1st Capturing Group `(\s?\d){9}`

`{9}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 9 times

A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

`\s?` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

`?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`\d` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)

[test it yourself](https://regex101.com/r/lHQFqo/1)

Comment: @ToddOwen thanks, but I'm not a legend about RegEx. [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) is a legend !

Comment: He just closed this for one that is relevant to c# not much help to me but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

- The pattern `[ ]*` will match any number of spaces (including 0).
- The pattern `([0-9]+)` will match 1 or more digits.
- The pattern `([0-9]*)` will any number of digits(including 0).

I think something like this could match everything for you:

```
GB[ ]*([0-9]+)[ ]*([0-9]*)[ ]*([0-9]*)[ ]*([0-9]*)
```

Match GB every time. Then 0 or more spaces, then at least 1 number, then spaces then numbers up to 4 times if 0 or more appear.

Let me know if more explanation is needed!

Comment: this works just the answer is  neater

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. I was definitely going for an explicit match. A shorter version for any future viewers could be: GB([ ]*([0-9]*))+