# Regular expression to ignore spaces between digits

Tags: regex

Is there a simple way to ignore whitespace between digits within a regular expression?

I want a RegEx to match on any 10 digit number, including numbers with spaces between them.

For example, the following 3 examples would match:

1. 4874526395
2. 4874 526 395
3. 48745 26395

`^\d{10}$` is the current regular expression, and expecting I'll need to use `\s` somewhere but unsure how.

Comment: just spaces (ascii 32) or any whitespace (tabs, newlines etc)?

Comment: you can try this one `^(\d *){10}$`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `^( *\d){10} *$` to match 10 digits with space characters before/after or in-between them.

[image: diagram of regex that allows spaces around]

<sup>[Regexper](https://regexper.com/#%5E%28%20*%5Cd%29%7B10%7D%20*%24)</sup>

If you only want to allow spaces in-between, but not before/after, you can use `^\d( *\d){9}$` instead.

[image: diagram of regex that doesn't allow spaces around]

<sup>[Regexper](https://regexper.com/#%5E%5Cd%28%20*%5Cd%29%7B9%7D%24)</sup>

Probably better understandable would be to remove space characters first.

```
string.replace(/ +/g, "").match(/^\d{10}$/)
```

If you want to match all whitespace (space, newline, tab, etc.), not just spaces, you can replace the space in the regex with `\s`.

Comment: Another user has already given this helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
^(\d\s*){9}\d$
```

Note that this does not match with leading or trailing whitespace. If you need to match those cases too, simply add a `\s*` before and after the regular expression (so `^\s*(\d\s*){9}\d\s*$`).

You can check this regexp interactively at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/b6SQWh/3) and generate code there, if needed.

Comment: `[\d]` is simply `\d`...

Comment: Thanks miile7, that's exactly what I needed. Nice and simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

I might be inclined to just strip off whitespace before checking the input for the correct number of digits:

```js
var input = "4874 526 395";
if (/^\d{10}$/.test(input.replace(/\s+/g, ""))) {
    console.log("MATCH");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With following code you can remove gap between numbers even you have string between them

String repl = "111 222 333".replaceAll("(?<=\d) +(?=\d)", "");
//=> Hello 111222333 World!

This regex "(?<=\d) +(?=\d)" makes sure to match space that are preceded and followed by a digit.

Answer (score 0):

There is a proposed way how to do so here:
[How to ignore whitespace in a regular expression subject string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590298/how-to-ignore-whitespace-in-a-regular-expression-subject-string)

But in this case it will be easier just to replace all whitespaces with empty string and use your regex:

```java
s.replaceAll("\\s+","").matches("^\\d{10}$")
```